# Google Analytics API ga:hour not working with ga:adClicks

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I tried using `ga:hour` having a `start-date` and `end-date` the same, but it returns `0` as the result. But when I try `ga:date`, it will return a result.

Here's an example:

```
start-date: 2015-04-02
end-date: 2015-04-02
metrics: ga:adClicks
dimensions: ga:hour
```

This query doesn't return a result. It returns `0` adClicks

But when I use this query:

```
start-date: 2015-04-02
end-date: 2015-04-02
metrics: ga:adClicks 
dimensions: ga:date
```

That returns a none zero `adClick` value

Why is that happening? Any help on this please!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

not all of the dimensions and metrics have data associated to each other.

[ga:hour](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_hour) and ga:minute are two that can case problems especially if combined with he adwords dimensions.  the data simply doesn't exist

try testing with the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)